# I want to build a nodejs REST api to allow only maximum of two devices to have access to an account with same login credentials

Tags: node.js

For example if i have build a mobile application and using the nodejs REST api for accessing the backend.
I want to restrict the access of the application with same login credentials on a maximum of two devices.
For example me and my friend can have have access to the application with same login credentials but a third friend must not be allowed to have access to the account with same login credentials.
Can it be implemented with some kind of token. Can anyone please help me in understanding the concept to implement this.

Comment: It can be implemented with a token, but I think it's important here to maintain sessions. Also, you need to keep track of who is connected to what account, and from what device. You'll definitely need unique identifiers, and to know how many logins the account is already utilizing. If a user logs out, remove that device from the list until they login again. Read up on [session management](https://codeforgeek.com/manage-session-using-node-js-express-4/). I have had good success using [PassportJS](http://www.passportjs.org/) for stuff like this :)

Comment: Thanks Evan Bechtol for suggesting the documentation. I will go through the document.

Answer (score 1):

Posting as an answer, since it does appear to be a solution.

It can be implemented with a token, but I think it's important here to maintain sessions. Also, you need to keep track of who is connected to what account, and from what device. You'll definitely need unique identifiers, and to know how many logins the account is already utilizing. If a user logs out, remove that device from the list until they login again. Read up on [session management](https://codeforgeek.com/manage-session-using-node-js-express-4/). I have had good success using [PassportJS](http://www.passportjs.org/) for stuff like this :)

Comment: Since the REST will be deployed on AWS and I could have 4 instance running then would the usage of sessions have any effect on AWS. Please correct me if I am wrong but I was advised that the sessions will work when only one instance is used. If there are multiple instance's than the sessions concept may not work. Is this theory true?

Comment: Think about your facebook login or google login. You have a session for each device that is logged in. You could implement this same style of approach. The session concept will still work because they will all pull from the same database.